# Formatting input type="text" in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a text field with `type='text'` and I am trying to format the text with commas. Example: `500000000` would become `500,000,000`.

I have the following code:

```js
function addComma(values) {
   values.value = values.value.replace(",", "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

if (document.getElementById("values"))
    payment = parseInt(document.getElementById("values").value);
```

```html
<label1>Rent</label1> <input id="values" type="text" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

However, it's printing `5,000,0,0,0,000` and the formatting is off for some reason. I also tried `.toLocaleString()`, but that doesn't seem to work either. What am I doing wrong here?

I was referred to a few other posts on Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to work out.

Comment: How about `(5000000000).toLocaleString()` instead?

Comment: To use `toLocaleString()` the string would first have to parsed to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addComma(values) {
  const v = values.value && new Number(values.value.replace(/,/g,''));
   values.value = v.toLocaleString();
}

if (document.getElementById("values"))
         payment = parseInt(document.getElementById("values").value);
```

```html
<label1>Rent</label1> <input id="values" type="text" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the number to a string, then manually iterating over each character and find places where a comma is needed.

```js
function formatNumber(number) {
  var str = number.toString();
  var offset = str.length % 3;
  var newStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 3 === offset) {
      newStr += ',';
    }
    newStr += str[i];
  }
  console.log(str, '=>', newStr);
}

formatNumber(5);
formatNumber(50);
formatNumber(500);
formatNumber(5000);
formatNumber(50000);
formatNumber(500000);
formatNumber(5000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a change event rather than a keyup event as change will only update the value when the input is no longer the focus. If you use keyup the code will try and reinterpret the new string you add back to the input as a number and throw an error.

Here's the code using [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) (just press tab after adding the number as if to move to the next input box):

```js
const values = document.querySelector('#values');
values.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

function handleChange(e) {
  const value = Number(e.target.value);
  const formatted = value.toLocaleString();
  values.value = formatted;
}
```

```html
<input id="values" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers posted before this one using the input field are ok to show how it works, but they are bugged as soon as you enter a new number when it has formatted to a string using `toLocaleString()`. For that reason I added the `toNumber()` function to be complete. In the example below I preform the following steps:

When user fills in a number in the input field and leaves the input field: Call `toString(e)` and make from the entered number a formatted string.

If the user again selects the input field, call `toNumber(e)` and format it back to a number.

This makes sure you won't get `NaN` when reselecting or will become completely unusable.

> The NaN property represents "Not-a-Number" value. This property indicates that a value is not a legal number.

It is still possible to add text in it, this will result in `NaN` as text cannot be formatted to a number. This could be filtered out in the `toString(e)` when necessary. I did this in the example below by adding `if (formatted !== 'NaN') {}` Only when it's not `NaN` it will set the value to the new formatted number. Else it won't do anything. Please note: a number with dots is a string in this case so wont work either.

```js
const values = document.querySelector('#values');
values.addEventListener('click', toNumber, false);
values.addEventListener('focusout', toString, false);

function toNumber(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const unformatted = value.replace(/\D/g,'');
  values.value = unformatted;
}

function toString(e) {
  const value = Number(e.target.value);
  const formatted = value.toLocaleString();
  if (formatted !== 'NaN') {
     values.value = formatted; 
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="values" type="text">
```

To fix that, you can also remove my addition and add a filter before the `toString(e)` does it's thing and filter the dots, text etc. so only the numbers remain.